# Issue in generating pdf using report lab in app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, http-headers, reportlab

I am trying to generate a pdf using reportlab with python in appengine. Now, whenever I call the function to generate pdf from the get(self) function it works perfectly but the same thing does not work when the function is called from post(self). As tested in logs, the function to generate pdf is running perfectly in both the cases. The problem seems to be in the pdf output (get and post). I have tried by keeping content disposition as attachment as well as inline but to no avail.

Here is part of code where generatePdf:

```
class PDFHandler(BlogHandler):


def get(self):

    self.render("create_offer_letter.html")
    candidate_name = "Siddhant"
    candidate_email ="ssjjs@ksks.com"
    candidate_phone = "939393993"
    address_part   = ['sjsjjs','ksksksks']
    confirmation_date = "22/07/2013"
    coursefee = "282828"
    admissionfee = "8388383"
    institute ="NIMT"
    course ="MBA"
    feeterm ="Trimester"
    #generatePdf(self,candidate_name,candidate_email,candidate_phone,address_part,confirmation_date,coursefee,admissionfee,institute,course, feeterm)
def post(self):   

    self.render("create_offer_letter.html")
    candidate_name = "Siddhant"
    candidate_email ="ssjjs@ksks.com"
    candidate_phone = "939393993"
    address_part   = ['sjsjjs','ksksksks']
    confirmation_date = "22/07/2013"
    coursefee = "282828"
    admissionfee = "8388383"
    institute ="NIMT"
    course ="MBA"
    feeterm ="Trimester"
    generatePdf(self,candidate_name,candidate_email,candidate_phone,address_part,confirmation_date,coursefee,admissionfee,institute,course, feeterm)
```

I guess it has to do something with http headers? I am not sure though.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "does not work?"

Comment: I mean since the pdf does not show up - when I call the function from get, pdf is downloaded whereas If I call the function from post, no pdf is downloaded.

Comment: You can see the difference here: 1) generatePdf called from Get [link](http://compute.nimtgroup.edu.in/createpdf) 2) generatePdf  called from Post [link](http://compute.nimtgroup.edu.in/createpdf2)